# Game Simulator Times Out

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first post on here. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my question.

I am a novice coder. I have a minor in Computer Science that I got a decade ago. I had an urge to do some simple coding, and an opportunity came up, so I did!

In developing a game, I wanted to run a program to determine the chances of given outcomes with given parameters. I excitedly reached the point where it was a go, but Google Scripts couldn't handle running the 60,000,000 possible scenarios in order to compute a win%.

I got, "error: Exceeded maximum execution time."

I'm just trying to find the shortest path between me and running this program. Ideas:

1) Is there a way to remove the maximum execution time and let it just take all day? Is there some other way I can get it to run in Google Scripts? 
2) Perhaps I can run a smaller number of trials by inputing random numbers. Is there a way to generate random numbers in Google Scripts?
3) Should I be doing this kind of thing in something besides Google Scripts? If so, is there a free/affordable compiler for Mac I should look into? I tried importing it into Xcode, but I'm bewildered and can't seem to get to a simple place to compile. Also, importing it to "C" is creating some compatibility issues; though I may just have to suck it up and retool it here.

For reference, here's the function that's timing it out:

```
function dieFeeder(winCount, fSkill, fMagnitude, fHeart, fDie1, fDie2, fDie3, fDie4,   fDie5, cSkill, cMagnitude, cHeart, cDie1, cDie2, cDie3, cDie4, cDie5){
// a parent function to function questionMatrix, feeds the changing dice into it

 var matrixWinner;  

//This 'for' clause keeps going until all dice permutations have been tried out

 for (var i=0; i<60466176; i++){
//This part changes the dice to go through all combiations in a way similar to counting in base 6

if (cDie5 == 7){
  cDie5 = 1;
  cDie4 = cDie4+1;
}

if (cDie4 == 7){
  cDie4 = 1;
  cDie3 = cDie3 +1;
}  

if (cDie3 == 7){
  cDie3 = 1;
  cDie2 = cDie2 +1;
}  

if (cDie2 == 7){
  cDie2 = 1;
  cDie1 = cDie1 +1;
}  

if (cDie1 == 7){
  cDie1 = 1;
  fDie5 = fDie5 +1;
}  

if (fDie5 == 7){
  fDie5 = 1;
  fDie4 = fDie4 +1;
}  

if (fDie4 == 7){
  fDie4 = 1;
  fDie3 = fDie3 +1;
}  

if (fDie3 == 7){
  fDie3 = 1;
  fDie2 = fDie2 +1;
}      

if (fDie2 == 7){
  fDie2 = 1;
  fDie1 = fDie1 +1;
}  

cDie5 = cDie5 + 1;

//This part checks to see who wins and increases the winCount if it was the Favorite

matrixWinner = questionMatrix(fSkill, fMagnitude, fHeart, fDie1, fDie2, fDie3, fDie4, fDie5, cSkill, cMagnitude, cHeart, cDie1, cDie2, cDie3, cDie4, cDie5);

if (matrixWinner == 'favorite'){

  winCount = winCount +1;

}

}

  return winCount;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no way to lift the maximum execution time. The limit is there so that other users (like me) can have time to run our scripts too! The solution to this problem is to break up your problem into many subproblems.

   - One solution would be to continue executing your script while your running time is under some threshold (say, 3 minutes) (i.e. keep track of how long your script has been running). Then save all state relating to your script (variables, etc.). Save these to ScriptDb. Then have your script run on a 5-minute trigger. When your script runs again, it reads the values from ScriptDb and picks up where it left off.
2. If  you're looking for random numbers, use `Math.random()`. Google Apps Scripts is built off of javascript, so basic javascript functions are available.
3. Relating to my answer to #2, what you have shown is entirely javascript, so you can just copy your code over to some webpage to run it. ([For testing, you can use jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)).
   Also you need to define `if (cDie5 == 7){`

Comment: Thank you for helping me to find jsfiddle! You are my hero! That totally worked. It's been so long since I've coded, I've forgotten that exhilarating feeling when you hit 'run' and it actually does what you want it to do. I quite literally hopped around my apartment in joy.